# Sorting a LIST based on another DICTIONARY

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a list and a dictionary:

```
list1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

dict1 = 
{
    "a": 4,
    "b": 3,
    "c": 5,
    "d": 9,
    "e": 2,
    "f": 8
}
```

What I want to do is sort list1   according to the corresponding value in dict1.

FOr the above example, I want list to become `["b", "a", "c", "d"]`, sorted according to their values..

I know it should be something like...

```
list2 = sorted(list1, key=dict1[x])
```

But I am stuck :((

Any help will be really appreciated

Answer (score 5):

key argument should be a function.

For example, using bound method `dict.__getitem__` or [`dict.get`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#dict.get):

```
>>> list1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
>>> dict1 = { "a": 4, "b": 3, "c": 5, "d": 9, "e": 2, "f": 8 }
>>> sorted(list1, key=dict1.__getitem__)
['b', 'a', 'c', 'd']
```

Comment: I upvoted, but you should consider using `dict1.__getitem__` so an exception is raised if the key is missing, instead of just using `None` for the key. In Python3, if any of the keys are missing, you would get `TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() < int()` which is less informative than a `KeyError`

Comment: @gnibbler, Thank you for comment. You're right. I updated the answer code to use `dict.__getitem__`.

Answer (score 4):

You're super close. `key` takes a function; you need to wrap retrieving values from `dict1` in a `lambda` (also pointed out by @falsetru):

```
>>> list2 = sorted(list1, key=lambda x: dict1[x])
>>> list2
 ['b', 'a', 'c', 'd']
```

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have been beaten to the canonical solutions, so here's a different tack

```
from operator import itemgetter
[k for (k, v) in sorted(dict1.items(), key=itemgetter(1)) if k in list1]
['b', 'a', 'c', 'd']
```

Answer (score 0):

The key stuff others have suggested is remarkably powerful.

However, I guess the old timer in me is thinking "why not just put the data in a list of class instances and provide `__lt__` and/or `__cmp__`?"  IMO, it'd be much more clear.